# How do I fix this flutter iOS error in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When I run the command "flutter build ios" - my app is built just fine. I can also run the app in the simulator. However, in Xcode, when I try to open the project, I get the error "unable to attach to DB: error: accessing build database"

This is the first time I've come across this problem on this app. Flutter doctor comes out clean, and nothing changes if I run "flutter clean" and build it again. I can't distribute my app until this is fixed.

Comment: Turns out I was still able to archive and distribute my app even with this error, so it turned out fine anyway.

Answer (score 7):

That happens at times when the iOS build gets corrupted for some reason.
Close Xcode.
Run `flutter clean`
After that `flutter build ios`
Open Xcode again and run your app.
This should generally solve your issue.

If that does not work, you can try this:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `cd ios`
3. `rm Podfile.lock`
4. `rm -rf Pods`
5. `pod deintegrate`
6. `pod cache clean`
7. `pod setup`
8. `pod install`

After that run `flutter build ios`

Comment: None of this worked unfortunately but thank you for trying.

Comment: This may or may not have been what happened in the past, but for me in September 2023, the flutter clean removed my generated localization files and so build failed. Simply go to your .arb files and generate those again and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, after i run this command

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Then i rerun the app and it came to life.